# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry unique values

Tags: php, duplicates, unique, fatal-error, exists

I  have problem I get error like this when I registration new user with Duplicate email or id which is unique:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'asma@gmail.com' for key 'email' in C:\wamp64\www\ITaidLibrary-8\registration_page.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\ITaidLibrary-8\registration_page.php(20): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}thrown in C:\wamp64\www\ITaidLibrary-8\registration_page.php on line 20

I want to show a message if it  already exists; how can I do it?

Comment: Is this your code or a downloaded tool that you didnt write

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example as source code, if it is your's.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply execute a select query and check if email existed already or not.
Also you can use try catch to show better error message